# Find a basis for the image and kernel of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $T(M) = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \end{array} \right)M-M\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \end{array} \right)$ is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ with respect to the basis $\mathcal{B} = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & -1 \end{array} \right),\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 \\
1 & -1 \end{array} \right),\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \end{array} \right),\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$

I'm told that the $\mathcal{B}$ matrix of the transformation is $\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
2 & 0&0&0 \\
0 & -2&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&\\
0&0&0&0 \end{array} \right)$, and I'm asked to find a basis for the kernel and image of $T$.

Can someone please explain how we can do this? I know a basis for the $im(T)$ would be given by the linearly independent columns in $\mathcal{B}$, but what are they in terms of $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$?

Comment: Each column in the $4 \times 4$ matrix corresponds to one of the four basis elements.

Comment: Is this true for any $\mathcal{B}$ matrix for a transformation with some basis?

Comment: With that thought, I can see that a basis for the image of $T$ will be $2M_1, -2M_2$ (where $M_1,M_2$ are the first two basis elements), but how can we find the kernel of $T$?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then yes. Given an ordered basis, there is a matrix corresponding to the transformation and the columns will correspond to the basis elements.

Comment: What is the kernel of the $4\times 4$ matrix?

Comment: @copper.hat I'm not sure. Usually I'd write $2M_1 = 0$ and $-2M2 = 0$, but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: The kernel of the $4 \times 4$ matrix is trivial to compute directly. Then map the results back to the $2 \times 2$ cases.

Comment: How do we find the kernel of the $4\times 4$ matrix?

Comment: The kernel of any matrix $A$ is the set of vectors $x$ such that $Ax=0$. In this case of a diagonal matrix this is trivial to compute explicitly.

Comment: That would be any vector $x$ of the form $[0 0 a b]^T$?

Comment: Correct. That would be the space spanned by the last two columns of the $4 \times 4$ matrix. What are the corresponding basis elements?

Comment: $M_3$ and $M_4$. Why does the kernel correspond to the last two columns, though? If I was given some other random $\mathcal{B}$ matrix and basis, what kind of generalization can I use to find the kernel?

Comment: The order of the columns must correspond to the basis order.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand. Had the matrix been $\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
2 & 0&1&0 \\
0 & -2&0&2\\
0&1&1&0&\\
4&0&0&0 \end{array} \right)$, for example, how can we find the image and kernel of $T$?

Comment: @copper.hat ^^^

Comment: Actually, suppose the $\mathcal{B}$ matrix had been $\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0&1&0 \\
-1 & 0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&\\
0&0&-1&0 \end{array} \right)$, what would a basis for the image and kernel be in this case? Would a basis for the image be $M_1,M_3$ and basis for the kernel be $M_1,M_2$?

Comment: In this particular case, since the matrix is diagonal, it is trivial to find the range and kernel. In general, you would need to use other techniques (row echelon form, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer as such, but another way of looking at the problem:

Note that the symmetric $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$  has an eigenvalue $\lambda_1=2$ corresponding to the eigenvector $v_1={1 \over \sqrt{2}} (1,1)^T$, and an eigenvalue $\lambda_2 = 0$ corresponding to the eigenvector $v_1={1 \over \sqrt{2}} (1,-1)^T$.

Note that the matrices $v_i v_j^T$ are a basis for the space of $2 \times 2$ matrices, and
$T(v_i v_j^T) = (\lambda_i - \lambda_j)v_i v_j^T$. Hence $T$ is diagonal in the basis $v_i v_j^T$, and we see that $\ker T = \operatorname{sp} \{ v_1 v_1^T, v_2 v_2^T  \}$, and ${\cal R} T = \operatorname{sp} \{ v_1 v_2^T, v_2 v_1^T  \}$.